# Convert IEnumerable<T> to string[]

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

i have an entity called Product

```
class Product
{
     public Id { get; set; }
     public Name { get; set; }
}
```

and i have a list of all products:

```
IEnumerable<Product> products = _productRepository.GetAll()
```

i want to get an array of strings from this list of products this array will contains the product Id + Product Name, so when i try to cast it using the following code:

```
string[] s = products.Cast<string>().ToArray();
```

i got the following exception:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'Product' to type 'System.String'
```

the exception really makes alot fo scence, so if i had a method

```
string ProductToString(Product p)
{
    return p.Name;
}
```

or an override to ToString() for the product object so how i can use this method to get the list of string[] from IEnumerable ?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Well, given that method you can use<sup>1</sup>:

```
string[] s = products.Select<string>(ProductToString).ToArray();
```

However, it would be more idiomatic to do this *without* a separate method, usually, using a lambda expression:

```
// Matches ProductToString, but not your description
string[] s = products.Select(p => p.Name).ToArray();
```

I'd only use a separate method if it was going to be called from various places (ensuring consistency) or did a lot of work.

EDIT: I've just noticed that your *description* (wanting ID + name) doesn't actually match the `ProductToString` method you've given (which just gives the name). For the ID + name I'd use:

```
string[] s = products.Select(p => p.ID + " " + p.Name).ToArray();
```

or

```
string[] s = products.Select(p => string.Format("{0} {1}", p.ID, p.Name))
                     .ToArray();
```

Or you could just change your `ProductToString` method, of course.

Alternatively, you could override `ToString()` in `Product`, if this is *usually* how you want to convert a `Product` to a `string`. You could then either use a method group conversion or a lambda expression to call `ToString`.

---

<sup>1</sup> It's possible that you don't need to specify the type argument explicitly - that:

```
string[] s = products.Select(ProductToString).ToArray();
```

will work fine - the rules for type inference and method group conversions always confuse me and the compiler behaviour has changed slightly over time. A quick test just now looks like it *does* work, but there could be subtleties in *slightly* different situations.

Comment: IMHO you don't have to write down the `<string>` in there and of course you beat me by 30secs ....

Comment: @CarstenKönig: It *may* depend on which version of the compiler you're using. There were subtle changes in the v4 compiler, IIRC. I was adding a note about that around the time you were commenting :)

Answer (score 4):

```
string[] s = products.Select(p => p.Name).ToArray();
```

Or, if you need Id + Name:

```
string[] s = products.Select(p => p.Id + ' ' + p.Name).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

use

```
string[] s = (from p in products select p.Id.ToString() + " " + p.Name.ToString()).ToArray();
```

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me:

```
String.Join(";", mi_customer.Select(a => a.Id).Cast<string>().ToArray());
```

Where `mi_customer` must be your object, in my case is a table.